# Dialog Window moved to background when opening CommonFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

From my MainWindow the user can open a custom dialog using the menu. This custom dialog offers the possibility to select a path using the CommonFileDialog.

The CommonFileDialog opens as it should, however, at the same time the custom dialog is moved behind the MainWindow. Now when the user exits this CommonFileDialog by either selecting or cancelling, the MainWindow is shown on top while the custom dialog is in the background.

This is really unintuive. What I want is that the windows behave like a normal stack, meaning that they spawn on top of each other and one exits them in reverse order.

Does anyone have an idea why the windows behave the way they do and how I could fix it?

Comment: solved it as in the answer posted by MethodMan. Thanks for that :) The trick was to set the Owner property of my cutstom dialog to the MainWindow